# Осложненное или сложное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

*Мне стало легко, будто камень с души свалился.*

Здравствуйте! Я правильно понимаю, что это предложение следует рассматривать как простое осложненное, а не сложное?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным сравнительным.

Comment: Спасибо! Но меня смущает то, что "камень с души свалился"- это фразеологизм, следовательно, как и цельное словосочетание, выполняет функцию одного члена предложения. Получается, нельзя его рассматривать как вторую грамматическую основу этого предложения.